# Action bar option items menu icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, optionmenu

Does anyone know how to add "menu" text under the dots menu icons in action bar?

Also, how can I make my option menu items to display the icon in Android 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add text under the default menu icon in the 4.0 Action bar, you do however have two alternatives

1) You can create your own icon that includes the text 'Menu' (Unfavourable)

2) Create a custom menu item with the dots image and the properties so that the text appears next to it.

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

Take a look at [The Android SDK Documentation on Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to see how to create custom items and make them perform tasks.